# How in Kendo to set it is declarative the JavaScript function in a template?

Tags: templates, kendo-ui

How in Kendo to set it is declarative the JavaScript function in a template?

```
<div id="items_#:idItem#"
          data-role="sortable"          
          data-cursor="move"
          data-axis="x"
          data-hint="???">
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you write this template?

Comment: <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="item_template">

Comment: And where do you use it?

Comment: var items_viewModel = kendo.observable({
        srcItems: new kendo.data.DataSource({.}),
        onHint: function (e) {.}
      });

Comment: kendo.bind("#items_list", items_viewModel);